# How can i set number of maxFile in react-native-image-crop-picker in Android in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-image-picker

I want to select only 5 image ,when gallary will open.but it is giving me chance to select all gallary images...in Android (React Native)

const openGalary = () => {
ImagePicker.openPicker({
mediaType:'photo',
width: 300,
height: 400,
multiple: true,
}).then((resp) => {
setLoading(true)
console.log("ImageFromGallary====>", resp)
setAllImages(resp);
setshowFlatList(resp.length > 1 ? true : false)
setshowCaptureImage(true)
let arra = resp.map(item=>item.path)
setFlatListData(arra)
setImageFromGallary(resp[0].path)
console.log("Imagessssssss===>",arra)
setLoading(false)
});
};

Comment: Currently the library doesn't expose apis for that, you could try handle that on your end  checking if the returned array of images length is less than 5